# Converting style tags of JSP into CSS entries

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have couple of tags in jsp as below

```
<style type="text/css">
    #mask {
        display: none;
        cursor: wait;
        z-index: 99999;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    }
</style>

<div id="mask">
    <div style="position: absolute; top : 300px; left : 550px; text-align : center; vertical-align: middle;font-family: arial,helvetica,verdana,sans-serif; color : red; font-size : 16px; font-weight : bold; text-decoration: underline;">
        <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/progress.gif" />
        <br/>loading
    </div>
</div>
```

When I tried to include them as CSS entries, I am not getting the output correctly.

```css
.busyDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 550px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana, sans - serif;
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.busyStyle {
    display: none;
    cursor: wait;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100 % ;
    width: 100 % ;
    background-color: white;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 70);
}
```

I used them as

```
<style type="text/css" class="busyStyle">
    #mask {}
</style>

<div id="mask">
    <div class="busyDiv">
        <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/progress.gif" />
        <br/>loading
    </div>
</div>
```

When I used CSS entries as above, the functionality is not working as expected?

Did I miss something ? (it works when I keep the tags in jsp as they are, but I want to separate the styles into CSS entries)

Comment: Don't class your style sheet, class your div with `class="busyStyle"`

Comment: Tried that one as well, but my gif is not being displayed as I defined it in the css entry "busyDiv"

Comment: div should be classed as "busyDiv" right ? why "busyStyle" ?

Comment: `<div id="mask">` should be `<div class="busyStyle">`

Comment: Sorry, it is not working

Comment: still the css entry is not applicable.

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle?  With everything set to display:none by default, we need more actions to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Man, try to learn the basics of css, what you are trying to do its entirely wrong in so many levels.

Comment: I understand but am completely new to CSS stuff. Am trying to find a way of achieving this

Answer (score 0):

I changed the styles as below to make it work

## in CSS

```
.hiddenDiv {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}

.visibleDiv {
    display: none;
}

.hiddenStyle {
    cursor: wait;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

.busyStyle {
        position: absolute;
        top: 300px;
        left: 550px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana, sans - serif;
        color: red;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
}
```

## in JS

```
function showBusy() {
    document.getElementById('mask').className = 'hiddenStyle';
    return false;
    }
```

## in JSP

```
<div id="mask" class="hiddenDiv">
        <div class="busyStyle">
            <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/progress.gif" />
            <br/>loading
        </div>
</div>
```